# Protected access on VPS to important files

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

PROBLEM:

My website has denied access to files outside of `/var/www/html/` directory.

DESCRIPTION:

My website is running from `/var/www/html/` directory on a VPS.
I'd like my website to access some important files from `/var/www/safe/` directory (like it does on my local computer). Unfortunately access to files on this ***safe*** directory is denied and systematically restricted even when I change permissions.

QUESTIONS:

- Is this the correct way to protect and access some important files?
- Is there a better solution to protect such files?

Comment: There are many possible ways to protect important files. The method depends upon how you intend to use the files, and the types of attack you intend to protect them from.

Comment: What may be the problem or what is the correct way to make my solution working well?

Comment: What are the contents of the "safe" directory. Does it contain data (database etc.) files used by scripts under "html" directory or does it contain the html pages and/or scripts themselves *that need to be accessed by the web server itself*?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli This directory contains scripts with fragile data and the website needs access to display it somewhere.

Comment: Your problem description is not clear. What do you mean with "the website": Is it a collection of PHP scripts or something else coded in another language? Data access will depend heavily on how your "web site" is coded and your "fragile data" is stored: Is it in MySQL or any other kind of database system?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Maybe that will better describe what I want. I want `www.mydomain.com/index.php` file to access `foo.php` file from `/var/www/safe/` directory. I do **not** want to get `/safe/` folder to be visible from `mydomain.com/safe/` url, but I still want to access `/var/www/safe/foo.php` file from `/var/www/html/index.php` file. I see it's possible on my local computer, but on my VPS it returns 'Permission denied' message.

Comment: This depends on the user id running your PHP scripts. For Apache web server, the user id is `www-data`. You should give read and/or write permissions to `www-data` for your "safe" files. Use `setfacl` command for doing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103240/discussion-between-fedonkadifeli-and-dryhay).

Comment: The normal way to do this is to add an [`.htaccess` file](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/)  to the directory (or the root of your server) to prevent direct access. This prevents getting the file by foring a URL (`http:server//Path/to/file`) but doesn't prevent PHP code or whatever run on the server to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends highly on what you are trying to do. For example, the default user running the *Apache Web Server* is `www-data`. If you want a script being run by Apache Server to read-access a file that it does not have read access, you can use the following command:

```
setfacl -m u:www-data:r /path/to/file
```

To give write access the another file for example use:

```
setfacl -m u:www-data:w /path/to/another/file
```

See https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/setfacl.1.html